# App Lock Library for Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add applock library in one of my android application. I want secure my ShowContentActivity activity with lock before open it. I have found good library [here](https://github.com/mattsilber/applock).

My java code for ShowContentActivity is like below now.

```
public void showContent(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(LockActivity.this, ShowContentActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

I have followed instruction in library page for implement it. But I am confused and not able to use. Anybody please suggest me how can I create lock and always use it before open my activity ?

Thanks

My Full Class is like below

```
public class LockActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
/**
 * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
 * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
 */
private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

/**
 * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
 * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
 */
private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

/**
 * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
 * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
 */
private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
private View mContentView;
private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

        // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
        // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
        // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
};
private View mControlsView;
private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Delayed display of UI elements
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.show();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};
private boolean mVisible;
private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        hide();
    }
};
/**
 * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
 * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
 * while interacting with activity UI.
 */
private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (AUTO_HIDE) {
            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock);

    mVisible = true;
    mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);


    // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
    mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            toggle();
        }
    });

    // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
    // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
    // while interacting with the UI.
    findViewById(R.id.unlock).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
    // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
    // are available.
    delayedHide(100);
}

private void toggle() {
    if (mVisible) {
        hide();
    } else {
        show();
    }
}

private void hide() {
    // Hide UI first
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.hide();
    }
    mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mVisible = false;

    // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
}

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private void show() {
    // Show the system bar
    mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    mVisible = true;

    // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
}

/**
 * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
 * previously scheduled calls.
 */
private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
}

public void showContent(View view) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(LockActivity.this, ShowContentActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }




}
```

Comment: are u adding method in `onCreate`. Please add more code

Comment: @W4R10CK I am not adding it on onCreate...**showContent** is button and I want lock on that...Thanks

Comment: can u add more code of this method or code of whole class.

Comment: @W4R10CK I have added full class...Thanks

Comment: where u calling `showContent` method.?

Comment: last lines of code...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your [issue](https://github.com/mattsilber/applock/issues/2) this morning and responded there with this (but I'll go into a bit more detail here):

First, prompt the user to create a pass code before trying to lock the Activity. If they haven't created a PIN, then there's nothing for them to unlock:

```
new CreateLockDialogBuilder(Activity, 
    new LockCreationListener(){
        public void onLockCanceled(){ } // Dialog was closed without entry
        public void onLockSuccessful(){
            // They've created a PIN, so now you can use the unlocking mechanisms
            doSomethingOnAppLocked();
        }
    })
    .show();
```

After they've locked it, just wrap your Intent in the check dialog within your showContent(View) method:

```
ActionLockingHelper.unlockIfRequired(Activity, new UnlockEventListener(){
    public void onCanceled(){ } // Dialog was closed without entry
    public void onUnlockFailed(String reason){ } // Not called with default Dialog, instead is handled internally
    public void onUnlockSuccessful(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(LockActivity.this, ShowContentActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

The above was taken directly from the readme on the home page of the [repo](https://github.com/mattsilber/applock). There's more there if you want to go further into detail, such as extending the LockableCompatActivity to fit with your app's architecture.

Comment: ! Thanks it have solved my issue....but sometime application not showing lock activity and going directly in next activity which should open only after unlock. I have posted code in Libray at GitHub...Please check and let me know if there any issue remain in it. I am not getting any error during this

Comment: The default unlock duration is 15 minutes. If you want it to lock every single time the Activity is paused (even if the screen is just turned off for a tenth of a second), then you need to override `R.integer.pin__default_activity_lock_reenable_minutes` and set the value to 0